# Javas DecimalFormat: how to reject "invalid" input with grouped decimals?

Tags: java, grouping, number-formatting

When using the following NumberFormat:

```
    NumberFormat amountFormat = NumberFormat
        .getNumberInstance(I18N.getThreadLocale());
    amountFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    amountFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
```

I get the following results when parsing via

```
    System.out.println(amountFormat.parse(value));
```

- 10,50 => 1050
- 10,5 => 105
- 0,25 => 25

I know that in Locale.ENGLISH the "," is the group separator. But I don't think that the above results make sense. And our customers get weird about this formatting.

How can I disable this grouping?

I would like to have the following results:

- 10,50 => ParseException
- 10,5 => ParseException
- 0,25 => ParseException

Is there a standard way to do this? Or do I have to program my own NumberFormat?

Comment: Why not just search for the comma before passing it to the parse value? If you want to get a Format Exception you could replace the comma with another invalid character.

Comment: @kgiannakakis: Of course I know how I could do it programmatically. But I don't understand why it is solved this way? I just wanted to know if and how it should be done with the JSE libs.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206371/how-to-get-the-same-value-as-the-user-is-seeing-from-a-jformattedtextfield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is the grouping character (',' in an English locale). To disable grouping support for the NumberFormat instance, you can simply invoke setGroupingUsed(false).

This however, leads to a different problem, namely that NumberFormat parses from the beginning of the string, until it reaches an unknown character. parse("12foo") will return 12, just as parse("10,50") will return 10 if grouping is disabled. To check if the entire input string was actually parsed, you have to use the parse methods with a ParsePosition argument and check its index and if the input string was parsed to the end or if the parser stopped at an earlier position in the string.