# How to get the same value as the user is seeing from a JFormattedTextField?

Tags: java, swing, validation, number-formatting, jformattedtextfield

I'm using a `NumberFormatter` and `JFormattedTextField`, but the `.getValue()` doesn't return the same value as the user is seeing.

I think the input-string is parsed using NumberFormats parse-method, and I get the Numberformat from `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();` with the actual Locale. So I don't think I easily can extend it and write my own parse-method?

**In example**, if the user types `1234.487`
the `getValue()` will return:
`1234.487` but the user will be displayed `1,234.49`

**Another example**, using `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();`. The user types `1234.487` and the `getValue()` will return `1234.487` but the user will be displayed `$1,234.49`

**Instead**, I want an ParseException be generated if the Formatter can't format the value without rounding. Same thing if the user types `4.35b6`, by default the formatter will display `4.35` and the value will be `4.35`, but I want a ParseException, because the user typed in an **invalid** value.

Here is the code that I have tried with:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
final JFormattedTextField ftf = new JFormattedTextField(nf);
ftf.setValue(new BigDecimal("1234.50"));

// Print the value from ftf
final JTextField txt = new JTextField(12);
txt.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        txt.setText(ftf.getValue().toString());
    }
});
```

**How to get the same value as the user is seeing?**

Comment: This question is related, and will improve the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680120/javas-decimalformat-how-to-reject-invalid-input-with-grouped-decimals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should extend `NumberFormatter` rather than `NumberFormat` and override `stringToValue` so that it verifies that when the string is parsed you get back the original value:

```
class StrictNumberFormatter extends javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter {
    @Override
    public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
        Object parsedValue = super.stringToValue(text);
        String expectedText = super.valueToString(parsedValue);
        if (! super.stringToValue(expectedText).equals(parsedValue)) {
            throw new ParseException("Rounding occurred", 0);
        }
        return parsedValue;
    }

    public StrictNumberFormatter(NumberFormat nf) {
        super(nf);
    }
}

NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter formatter = new StrictNumberFormatter(nf);
final JFormattedTextField ftf = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
ftf.setValue(new BigDecimal("1234.50"));
```

This formatter will reject the new text if the values before and after rounding do not match.

Note: this compares the *values*, not the strings.  It will tolerate changes like removing grouping characters (`"$1,000"` => `"$1000"`) and trailing zeros (`"$1.20"` => `"$1.2"`).  Basically if the `NumberFormat` returns the same value then it is acceptable.  But any restrictions imposed by the `NumberFormat` still apply, e.g. you must not remove the currency symbol or insert leading spaces etc.

Comment: @Ash, yes I just tried it with `getCurrencyInstance()`.  It ought to work with any valid `NumberFormat`.

Comment: It was much easier to edit the textfield using this solution, so I will go with this instead. Thanks!

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for an elegant solution.  This problem had me stumped!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
txt.setText(ftf.getFormatter().valueToString(ftf.getValue()));
```

You'll also have to handle the `java.text.ParseException` that the `valueToString` method throws.

**Edit:**
The formatter can be set to disallow invalid entries altogether, which might help:

```
    ((DefaultFormatter)ftf.getFormatter()).setAllowsInvalid( false );
```

Comment: That doesn't work. You then have to parse the string again, because the string contains formatting, like currencysymbol and grouping of the digits. And I don't think there is a parser for strings with currencysymbols?

Comment: When I run your code (with the above change) and type "1234.487" I see "1,234.49" in both fields. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: No, I want the value, not the String, so I can do calculations. If I wanted it that way I could use getText(). I think that if the user types three fraction digits a ParseException should be generated and the formatter should not do rounding, that's important. If I do like your example, the value has the grouping-symbol between 1 and 2, so I have to parse it again.

Comment: @Sanoj: Okay, so you want the formatter to tell you (via ParseException) as soon as the user enters something that's invalid?

Comment: This is pretty tricky, given the distinction that the formatter makes between value and text. You can set the default formatter to disallow invalid entries altogether - would that help?

Comment: It was pretty hard to edit the text if .setAllowsInvalid() is set to False, so I will go with finnw's solution instead. Specially if it is a decimal number. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, no problem. I liked finnw's solution too.